# SocketJS + Spring Boot > Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sockets, stomp

I'm creating a SocketJS (that uses STOMP) app with Spring Boot, and I keep getting this error whenever my app starts:

```
caught Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet
    at SockJS.send (main.js:161:1)
    at Client._transmit (stomp.js:159:1)
    at Client.disconnect (stomp.js:341:1)
    at ChatRoom.tsx:37:1
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22932:1)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23100:1)
    at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25207:1)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:1)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27324:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:1)
S
```

Then, on the backend I get this error:

```
 WebSocketSession[2 current WS(2)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 2 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(2)-CONNECTED(2)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 16, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 18], outboundChannel[pool size = 2, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 8, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 3, completed tasks = 9]
2023-10-15T15:13:35.507+13:00 ERROR 10628 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : Error publishing SessionDisconnectEvent[sessionId=stpnlchb, CloseStatus[code=1000, reason=null]]
```

Front-end React code:

```
import { Button, Flex, Input, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import { Client, Message, over } from "stompjs";

interface ChatMessage {
    content: string
    sender: string
    type: 'CHAT' | 'JOIN' | 'LEAVE'
}

interface ChatRoomProps {
    username: string
}

export default function ChatRoom(props: ChatRoomProps) {
    const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string | null>(null)
    const [messageStream, setMessageStream] = useState<ChatMessage[]>([])
    const [stompClient, setStompClient] = useState<Client | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws')
        const client: Client = over(socket)

        client.connect({}, () => {
            client.send('/chat.addUser', {}, JSON.stringify({ content: '', sender: props.username, type: 'JOIN' }))
            client.subscribe('/topic/public', messageReceivedCallbackHandler)

            setIsLoading(false)
        }, errorCallbackHandler)

        setStompClient(client)

        return () => {
            socket.close()
            client.disconnect(() => {})
        }
    }, [])

    function messageReceivedCallbackHandler(payload: Message): void {
        const message: ChatMessage = JSON.parse(payload.body)

        setMessageStream(prevMessageStream => [...prevMessageStream, message])
    }

    function errorCallbackHandler(): void {
        setError(true)
    }

    function messageChangeHandler(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
        setMessage(e.target.value)
    }

    function sendClickHandler(): void {
        if (message && stompClient) {
            const chatMessage: ChatMessage = {
                content: message,
                sender: props.username,
                type: 'CHAT'
            }

            stompClient.send('/chat.sendMessage', {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage))

            setMessage(null)
            
            const inputElement = document.getElementById('msg-input') as HTMLInputElement
            inputElement.value = ''
        }
    }

    return (
        <Flex
            width='750px'
            height='750px'
            flexDirection='column'
            gap='16px'
            background='white'
            alignItems='center'
            padding='42px'
            overflow='clip'
        >
            <Text fontSize='lg' fontWeight='bold'>Spring WebSocket Chat Demo - By Alibou</Text>

            {error && <Text>Error connecting to server</Text>}

            {loading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : (
                <Flex flexDirection='column' textAlign='center' overflowY='scroll' width='100%'>
                    {messageStream.map((message, index) => (
                        <>
                            {message.type === 'CHAT' && <Text key={index}><b>{message.sender}</b>: {message.content}</Text>}
                            {message.type === 'JOIN' && <Text key={index}><b>{message.sender}</b> joined</Text>}
                            {message.type === 'LEAVE' && <Text key={index}><b>{message.sender}</b> left</Text>}
                        </>
                    ))}
                </Flex>
            )}


            <Flex marginTop='auto' width='100%' gap='16px'>
                <Input id='msg-input' placeholder='Type a message' marginTop='auto' onChange={messageChangeHandler} />
                
                <Button colorScheme='blue' onClick={sendClickHandler}>Send</Button>
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
    )
}
```

Java backend:

```
package com.example.socket.controller;

import com.example.socket.controller.model.ChatMessage;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Objects;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(
        @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor
    ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes()).put("username", chatMessage.getSender());

        return chatMessage;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.socket.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.socket.config;

import com.example.socket.controller.model.ChatMessage;
import com.example.socket.controller.model.MessageType;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionDisconnectEvent;

import java.util.Objects;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messageTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketEventListener(SimpMessageSendingOperations messageTemplate) {
        this.messageTemplate = messageTemplate;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        String username = Objects.requireNonNull(headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes()).get("username").toString();

        log.info(STR."User disconnected: \{username}");

        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setType(MessageType.LEAVE);
        chatMessage.setSender(username);

        messageTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
    }
}
```

I've got no idea why this is happening. I've tried to solve it for some time, but I don't know what the source of the problem is. I suspect the issue is somewhere on the frontend though.

**Update:**

After refactoring the code to something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws')

        socket.onopen = () => {
            const client = over(socket)
            setStompClient(client)

            client.connect({}, () => {
                client.send('/chat.addUser', {}, JSON.stringify({ content: '', sender: props.username, type: 'JOIN' }))
                client.subscribe('/topic/public', messageReceivedCallbackHandler)

                setIsLoading(false)
            }, errorCallbackHandler)
        }

        return () => {
            socket.close()
            stompClient?.disconnect(() => {})
        }
    }, [])
```

It seems to just be stuck on 'CONNECTING...', which is odd.

Stack trace:

```
2023-10-19T17:23:06.840+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /ws/463/evl1y24y/websocket
2023-10-19T17:23:06.840+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-10-19T17:23:06.840+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-10-19T17:23:06.841+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-10-19T17:23:06.841+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/ws/463/evl1y24y/websocket", parameters={}
2023-10-19T17:23:06.841+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping      : Mapped to org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@6b350309
2023-10-19T17:23:06.842+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Processing transport request: GET http://localhost:8080/ws/463/evl1y24y/websocket
2023-10-19T17:23:06.938+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.apache.tomcat.util.collections.LocalStrings)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResource(org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/LocalStrings.properties)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Resource not found, returning null
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.apache.tomcat.util.collections.LocalStrings_en)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2023-10-19T17:23:06.939+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResource(org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/LocalStrings_en.properties)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Resource not found, returning null
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.apache.tomcat.util.collections.LocalStrings_en_NZ)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResource(org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/LocalStrings_en_NZ.properties)
2023-10-19T17:23:06.940+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a
2023-10-19T17:23:06.941+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Resource not found, returning null
2023-10-19T17:23:06.962+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 101 SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS
2023-10-19T17:23:06.964+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@718be7b6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7f4c17f7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55430]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [UPGRADING]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.001+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession    : Created WebSocket session [0]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.006+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : New WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=evl1y24y]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.027+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : wsFrameServer.onDataAvailable
2023-10-19T17:23:07.028+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@718be7b6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7f4c17f7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55430]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.028+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@718be7b6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7f4c17f7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55430]], Read direct from socket: [0]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.028+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.h.u.UpgradeProcessorInternal       : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@718be7b6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7f4c17f7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55430]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [UPGRADED]
2023-10-19T17:23:07.029+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@718be7b6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7f4c17f7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55430]]
2023-10-19T17:23:44.841+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [alina-utility-1] o.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase    : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1697689424841 sessioncount 0
2023-10-19T17:23:44.842+13:00 DEBUG 26253 --- [alina-utility-1] o.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase    : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
```

I also discovered these logs which could be indicating something:

```
2023-10-22T12:39:58.952+13:00 DEBUG 6918 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: (port 42091) connection closed
2023-10-22T12:39:58.952+13:00 DEBUG 6918 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: close connection, socket: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=46880,localport=42091]
2023-10-22T12:39:58.952+13:00 DEBUG 6918 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: socket close: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=46880,localport=42091]
```

Comment: can you set log-level to debug and check the exception stack-trace

Comment: @i_m_js Ok done

Comment: Are you using this org.apache.tomcat.util anywhere in your code? I see class not found exception in the logs that you have provided.

Comment: Can you provide your codebase via github to fix the issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring `registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");` This means topics have to include the prefix `/app`.
Instead of

```
client.send('/chat.addUser', {}, JSON.stringify({ content: '', sender: props.username, type: 'JOIN' }))
stompClient.send('/chat.sendMessage', {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage))
```

Try this

```
client.send('/app/chat.addUser', {}, JSON.stringify({ content: '', sender: props.username, type: 'JOIN' }))
stompClient.send('/app/chat.sendMessage', {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage))
```

This is the definition in spring [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE_to_4.0.2.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/MessageBrokerRegistry.html)

> Configure one or more prefixes to filter destinations targeting
> application annotated methods. For example destinations prefixed with
> "/app" may be processed by annotated methods while other destinations
> may target the message broker (e.g. "/topic", "/queue"). When messages
> are processed, the matching prefix is removed from the destination in
> order to form the lookup path. This means annotations should not
> contain the destination prefix.
>
> Prefixes that do not have a trailing slash will have one automatically
> appended.

Also make sure that you're allowing `cors` and security permission for path `/ws` because there is http call for checking socket info.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @thebluepandabear And make sure that you're allowing cors and security for path `/ws` because there are some http call for checking socket info.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, i would suggest you to read the official Stompjs guide page, and avoid SockJs as it states here, because it generates more problems than it solves:

> In reality, there is very little chance that you need SockJS. Unless you know, for sure, you do not need SockJS.

[Stomp-js docs](https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/rx-stomp/using-stomp-with-sockjs.html#do-you-need-sockjs)

So, in your spring config file, you can remove the ".withSockJS();" part. The rest of the config looks fine.

You can create the websocket client on front end, directly from Stompjs, like that:

```
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';

const newClient = new Client({
  // Remember Stomp goes over WS protocol, not on HTTP like SockJs
  brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/ws", 

  // Optional configurations
  connectHeaders: {
    login: "yyy",
    passcode: "xxx"
  },
  debug: function (str) {
    console.log(str);
  },
  reconnectDelay: 5000,
  heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
  heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,

  // Custom onConnect function (whatever you like, useState, etc.)
  onConnect: () => setConnected(true),

  onStompError: (frame) => {
    console.log('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
    console.log('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
  },
  onWebSocketError: (it) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(it));
  }
});

newClient.activate();
```

Other functions (subscribe, unsubscribe, publish, deactivate) are pretty straight forward.

(I strongly suggest you to use a React Context for the websocket operations, and be really aware where/when do you connect/disconnect,  if you want to avoid multiple socket connections per user nightmare)

The connectivity problem should still keep going with this changes, in my opinion, you should first test, that socket is connecting correctly without doing anything else.

I would remove the "client.send" and "client.subscribe" that you have in your onConnect function, and I would see if simple connection is working.

Check on your front-end dev-tools if, on network section, requests to /ws are successful or not. If not, provide also front-end logs or network requests statuses.